$ \sin \theta(E, F)=\inf \left\{|e-f|: e \in S_{E}, f \in F\right\} $, why $\theta(E, F)$ may not equal $\theta(F, E)$?
Let $E, F \in \mathcal{G}(V)$. The minimal angle $\theta(E, F) \in\left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ from $E$ to $F$ is defined by
$$
\sin \theta(E, F)=\inf \left\{|e-f|: e \in S_{E}, f \in F\right\}
$$
Roughly speaking, the minimal angle $\theta(E, F)$ will be small whenever $E$ is inclined towards $F$. Note that $\theta(E, F)$ may not equal $\theta(F, E)$.
How to understand the "inclined towards"? why $\theta(E, F)$ may not equal $\theta(F, E)$?
I get this problem from the Definition 8 of paper. I think $\theta(E, F)$  equal $\theta(F, E)$, but don't konw how to prove.
